# Modification of a dictionary in a yaml file using tabulated data in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dictionary, yaml

I'm trying to modify/update a yaml configuration file using python.
The section which a want to modify is a dictionary, here you have an example of the structure of this yaml file:

```
DEFAULT:
    zoneID_dictionary_2:      # Usual activity place.
        -1:     'Unknown zone'
        1:      'Zone XX 01'
        2:      'Zone XX 02'
        999:    'Unknown zone'
```

Using pandas I loaded a CSV file from where I'm going to extract the new dictionary needed. Here you have an extract of my code:

```
def yml_manager(config_template_file_path, output_file_path, customers_catchment_area_dict_file_path=None):

    # Load the template of the configuration file
    stream = open(config_template_file_path, 'r')
    config = yaml.load(stream=stream)

    # Update directories
    config['DEFAULT']['dir_path_1'] = '_new_path_1_'
    config['DEFAULT']['dir_path_2'] = '_new_path_2_'

    if customers_catchment_area_dict_file_path is not None:
        df = pandas.read_csv(customers_catchment_area_dict_file_path, sep=';') 
        config['DEFAULT']['zoneID_dict'] = {x: y for x, y in zip(df['zone_ID'].tolist(), df['zone_name'].tolist())}

    with open(output_file_path, 'w') as yml_file:
        yml_file.write(yaml.dump(data=config, default_flow_style=False))
        yml_file.close()
```

By using this code I have the following exception: **TypeError: data type not understood**/ while dumping the file. On the other side when I create the dictionary in the code, like this:

```
    d = {-1: 'Unknown zone',
         1: 'catchment_zone_01',
         2: 'catchment_zone_02'}
    config['DEFAULT']['zoneID_dict'] = d
```

The exception is not raised anymore.

Because of the context of this project i have to use YAML files and load the dictionary information from a CSV file having hundreds of lines (which I will clean using pandas), so any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance folks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, seems like when I try to dump the new file, yaml.dump cannot recognize the data type assigned to integers by pandas. So we can resolve this problem by adding a cast while creating the dictionary:

```
config['DEFAULT']['zoneID_dict'] = {int(x): y for x, y in zip(df['zone_ID'].tolist(), df['zone_name'].tolist())}
```